# Sort XML root based on inner Child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have following XML. Would like to have it sorted based on ChildID. The Parent node should also be moved as per childID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Parent>
    <Children>
      <Child>
        <setting ChildID="14" />
      </Child>
      <Child>
        <setting ChildID="27" />
      </Child>
    </Children>
    <Header>
      <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="1" />
    </Header>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Children>
      <Child>
        <setting ChildID="11" />
      </Child>
    </Children>
    <Header>
      <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="0" />
    </Header>
  </Parent>
</Root>
```

So final Ouput should be rearranged as below.  I am using XmlNodeList to load XML contents. Kindly advise.

```
    <Root>
      <Parent>
        <Children>
          <Child>
            <setting ChildID="11" />
          </Child>
        </Children>
        <Header>
          <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="0" />
        </Header>
      </Parent>
      <Parent>
        <Children>
          <Child>
            <setting ChildID="14" />
          </Child>
          <Child>
            <setting ChildID="27" />
          </Child>
        </Children>
        <Header>
          <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="1" />
        </Header>
      </Parent>
    </Root>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code (XSLT?) you have tried here so that we may assist you.

Comment: Note you actually changed the CHILD ELEMENT in your output, 14 now has a new parent, is that desired?  Why would 14 move but NOT 27?  What are the rules here?  Clearly and completely state the problem, then attempt some implementation of that - that is often most of the challenge with writing code.

Comment: You can use <xsl:sort> function order="ascending|descending" based on your needs, if you can share your xslt, we might be able to help more precisely.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Sorry for the typo. 14 and 27 are not supposed to move. Only 11,then 14,27. Have corrected the final XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by having an identity template, which will copy all nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, if you are sorting `Parent` nodes, start by having a template match at their parent element `Root`. Do the sorting as you apply the templates. Such as:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <!-- Select the target node to be sorted.
              This time, we select the first descendant node with
              an attribute ChildID -->
            <xsl:sort select="descendant::*/@ChildID[1]" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and that is it. The whole stylesheet is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="descendant::*/@ChildID" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try above implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Once issue is the sort by the attribute which is number SO you need to force that otherwise it will fail on stuff like `ChildID="111" and ChildID="21"` which would sort the first prior if using alpha sort.

You also have a 2 space indent.  Indent is NOT needed for most XML but you have it in there.  It would be faster (micro optimize) and smaller without indents but you provided output examples with it.  Some processors will do indents but might not 2 by default for example so we use this to be more exact at a processing cost.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
    <!-- two space indent -->
    <xsl:param name="indent-increment" select="'  '" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- no XML declaration -->
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>
    <!-- copy the root -->
    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <!-- force number type for attribute sort -->
                <xsl:sort select="descendant::*/@ChildID" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- more stuff for the indent -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:param name="indent" select="'&#xA;'"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="indent"
                select="concat($indent, $indent-increment)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:if test="*">
                <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Parent>
        <Children>
            <Child>
                <setting ChildID="14" />
            </Child>
            <Child>
                <setting ChildID="27" />
            </Child>
        </Children>
        <Header>
            <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="1" />
        </Header>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Children>
            <Child>
                <setting ChildID="111" />
            </Child>
        </Children>
        <Header>
            <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="3" />
        </Header>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Children>
            <Child>
                <setting ChildID="12" />
            </Child>
        </Children>
        <Header>
            <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="0" />
        </Header>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Children>
            <Child>
                <setting ChildID="11" />
            </Child>
        </Children>
        <Header>
            <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="0" />
        </Header>
    </Parent>
</Root>
```

Produced this:

```
<Root>
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <Child>
      <setting ChildID="11"/>
    </Child>
  </Children>
  <Header>
    <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="0"/>
  </Header>
</Parent>
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <Child>
      <setting ChildID="12"/>
    </Child>
  </Children>
  <Header>
    <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="0"/>
  </Header>
</Parent>
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <Child>
      <setting ChildID="14"/>
    </Child>
    <Child>
      <setting ChildID="27"/>
    </Child>
  </Children>
  <Header>
    <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="1"/>
  </Header>
</Parent>
<Parent>
  <Children>
    <Child>
      <setting ChildID="111"/>
    </Child>
  </Children>
  <Header>
    <parentsetting name="ParentPosition" value="3"/>
  </Header>
</Parent></Root>
```

Comment: You may have issues with multiple ChildID in a group with this.  I consider that another question as it is not specifically addressed in the question..

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback, I will try your above implementation.